# Assessing probability that one set of measurements extends the other with Kalman smoother

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kalman-filter, smoothing

I have two sets of N-dimensional measurements following each other with a certain time gap in between. Let's name those sets $A$ and $B$, respectively. All observations have constant Gaussian white noise characterized by the covariance matrix $R$.

The process is well-modelled in a linear Kalman filtering sense, i.e. defined state-transition model, observation model and process noise as matrices constant in time.

My goal is to assess how likely it is that measurements from $B$ are an extension of $A$. To do so I can apply Kalman smoothing jointly to those two sets of measurements and from the result I would like to get a test statistic that, in an ideal world, satisfies the following criteria:

- attributes lower score to longer gaps between the last measurement from $A$ and the first measurement from $B$ or attributes higher scores to more numerous $B$ set,
- its distribution (or asymptotical distribution) is known.

I was scratching my head trying to use the **likelihood-ratio test** but I couldn't figure out against what more general statistical model I should be testing.

The other approach is to decompose multivariate normal into 1-D normal distributions and apply N two-tailed tests for all measurements, but this introduces strong assumption of dimension independence (that's not always the case) and also it will be penalizing more numerous sets, where I would like to introduce the opposite - penalize longer gaps between sets and even possibly reward more numerous $A$ and $B$ sets.

Do you have some idea how I can achieve such metric?